# How to get an artifact in Maven Central show up in JCenter

Tags: maven, bintray, jcenter

I have published a small library to Maven Central ([it can be downloaded via web UI here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22single-table-bulk-id-strategy%22)). This was done more than a full day ago.

My understanding is that JCenter mirrors Maven Central, but for some reason I cannot find my artifact in [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) both via web interface and as part of Maven build.

Do I need to take some action to make it appear in JCenter too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two weeks later the artifact is now visible in JCenter. Apparently it just takes some time to appear there.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if you want to make sure that your library will exist in JCenter, you can [upload](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_howdoiuploadmystufftobintray.html) your library to Bintray under Maven repository, and request to [add it to JCenter](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_includingyourpackagesinjcenter.html).
Bintray can also save you the trouble of uploading your library to Maven Central, and [do it for you](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_syncingartifactswithmavencentral.html).

Enjoy